# How to package stand alone exe inside Visual Studio Installer maker?

Tags: visual-studio

Im currently using Visual Studio Installer to package my dll program. How to include stand alone executable program inside my installer project? Since my dll is using the exe(s) in order to run.

Note: For my development platform, I already have the exe(s) inside my c:\ directory. So I would like my installer to also copy the exe(s) to c: drive of other user's platform when they run my installer.

Comment: How to package a MSI and three EXE files into one single setup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the required exe during making the installer to the Application Folder.

Then change all the path that points to those required exe(s) so that it points to the exe(s) in the Application Folder. Shown below:

Instead of "C:\directory\file.exe" to Application.StartupPath & "\file.exe"

Application.StartupPath returns the path of the executable file that started the application.

So if you app is installed in "C:\Program Files\MyApp\program.exe" this would return "C:\Program Files\MyApp"

I hope this helps.